# How can I ensure CTRL+L always focusses the address bar, even when the find panel is open?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

When I am searching a page with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and then want to focus the address bar again with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, Chrome, Chromium and Edge won't let me, unless I close the find panel first, either with <kbd>ESC</kbd> or with the cross icon.

How can I ensure that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> *always* focusses the address bar, regardless of the status of the find panel?

I'm using Microsoft Edge Version 101.0.1210.32 (Official build) (64-bit) managed by my organization, so I cannot update.

---

On a different machine I use Brave (also Chrome based) on a Mac, and there the functionality is as I expect: <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (the Mac equivalent of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) always focusses the address bar.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't intentional Chromium functionality?  I attempted this workflow with both Chromium and Google Chrome and they both behaved identically to that have Edge.

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't tested it out in Google Chrome, but Brave (also Chrome based) on Mac does work as I prefer so I assumed that it was Edge being edgy. I'm happy to expand my question to Chrome though.